# What is considered a screen by react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What is considered a screen by react-navigation?

Is it any entry in the RouteConfigs (i.e. StackNavigator)? 
Does it also need to be an ES6 class?

I am trying to access the `this.props.navigation` but `props` is `undefined` and I suspect that it is because my component is a stateless functional component.
If I turn it into a class the props are there.

Is there a way to work with stateless functional components and navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with stateless components, you can’t access the props using `this.props`, as stateless means just a simple function (rather than a class instance) i.e. without `this`. So, you can access props using the function arguments instead. See the following two examples:

```
const StatelessComponent = props => (
    <div>{props.label}</div>
);
```

or alternatively:

```
const StatelessComponent = ({label , anotherProp}) => (
    <div>{label}</div>
);
```

So in your case, just simply access `props.navigation`.